# "Medium" size image displayed instead of "thumbnail" in only one post, other posts are fine

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

Please take a look at this cicada photo - http://photo.aseev.com/stock-photo/cicada-exuviae/ - below you will see 5 thumbnails, all of them are squared, except one (a bug on white background).

It is rectangular and it is actually the "medium" size (unlike 4 other thumbnails, which have correct paths to the "thumbnail" size image).

Removing the post and the image from media gallery and recreating the post doesn't help.

The thumbnail image for this file exists in the right directory and it is squared (*-150x150.jpg). In mySQL sizes are defined correctly for the thumbnail, from what I understood.

In media library, each photo has a thumbnail in front of its title, all of them squared except the one I have the problem with.

I upload images programmatically with wp_handle_upload, so maybe there was a mySQL input error.

Don't know where else to look. Anyone else experienced this? Is there a way I can fix it manually in the mySQL db?

Comment: Can you show your code that outputs the thumbnails?

Comment: I output it with the_post_thumbnail( array(50,50) ); the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); displays the squared one. I can use that, but I'd like to find out what the problem is, since in the media library displays it incorrectly as well.

Comment: Without seeing your code for setting up custom image sizes and/or for outputting the thumbnails, it's impossible to help.

Comment: I have no custom sizes specified in functions.php and I output images with the_post_thumbnail( array(50,50) );  $my_query = new wp_query($args);
 if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<h3>Similar Images: </h3>';
  echo '<div class="similar-images-box">';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
   $my_query->the_post();
  ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Stock image: <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(50,50) ); ?></a>
  <?php
  }
  echo '</div>';
 }
 wp_reset_query();</code>

Comment: I don't think it is a problem of output. As I mentioned, in media library this particular file also has the wrong size thumbnail. The rest are squared. Take a look - http://www.mediafire.com/view/678s4bd8sylqziz/wp-thumb-size.png

Comment: Alright, since there is not much activity here, I'm going to output the thumbnails with the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'), which displays squared images. So, if someone has the same problem, use the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') and scale it with CSS. But I'm still interested why this happens, so please send me a message if you know why.